# INSERT INTO..SELECT..ON DUPLICATE KEYS ambiguous ids

Tags: sql, mysql, insert-update, mysql-error-1052

I have the following table:

```
mysql> SELECT *  FROM  `bright_promotion_earnings`;
+----+----------+------------+----------+-------+
| id | promoter | generation | turnover | payed |
+----+----------+------------+----------+-------+
|  1 |        4 |          1 |       10 |     0 | 
|  3 |        4 |          5 |      100 |     0 | 
|  4 |        4 |          3 |    10000 |     1 | 
|  5 |        4 |          3 |      200 |     0 | 
+----+----------+------------+----------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is one unique key(promoter, generation, payed):

```
+---------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table                     | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| bright_promotion_earnings |          0 | promoter_2 |            1 | promoter    | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| bright_promotion_earnings |          0 | promoter_2 |            2 | generation  | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| bright_promotion_earnings |          0 | promoter_2 |            3 | payed       | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
+---------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I want to mark every earning for a promoter as paid by updating the same entry with paid=1 (if it exists).

So if I wanted to mark the earnings of promoter 4 as paid this is what the table should look like:

```
+----+----------+------------+----------+-------+
| id | promoter | generation | turnover | payed |
+----+----------+------------+----------+-------+
|  4 |        4 |          3 |    10200 |     1 | 
|  6 |        4 |          5 |      100 |     1 | 
|  7 |        4 |          1 |       10 |     1 | 
+----+----------+------------+----------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is my current approach(without the DELETE which is trivial):

```
INSERT INTO 
    bright_promotion_earnings
    (
        promoter,
        generation,
        turnover,
        payed
    )
SELECT 
    commission.promoter,
    commission.generation,
    commission.turnover as turnover2,
    '1' as payed
FROM  
    bright_promotion_earnings as commission
WHERE  
    promoter=4
    AND payed=0
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE turnover=turnover+turnover2;
```

But mysql keeps telling me that turnover is ambiguous:

```
#1052 - Column 'turnover' in field list is ambiguous
```

Does anybody have a hint as I can't alias the table that I'm inserting to.

How can I give the table I'm inserting to a name so that mysql can identify the column?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use aliases in an INSERT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702690/can-i-use-aliases-in-an-insert-statement)

Comment: @enharmonic Are you really asking me whether this answers the question I asked 11.5 years ago that has already been answered and accepted on the same day? :)

Comment: ugh, no, Stack Overflow "helpfully" included that "welcoming-sounding" text when I flagged this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a turnover field in both tables, so mysql can't decide which one you mean at the last row.

Comment: Yes I know that..that's exactly my problem.

The Question is:
How can I give the table I'm inserting a name so that mysql can identify the column?

Comment: wouldn't this work?
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bright_promotion_earnings.turnover = bright_promotion_earnings.turnover + commission.turnover2;

Comment: @Zed this solved the question for me. Why don't you post it as an answer? also, can an alias be applied to the table so that you could say `t.turnover`?