# Can I use aliases in an INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, insert, alias

Can we use aliases with insert into syntax?

None of the following work:

```
INSERT INTO tableblabla AS bla
INSERT INTO bla tableblabla
INSERT INTO tableblabla bla
```

I can't seem to find any information about this; is there a valid way to use aliases in an INSERT statement?

About the possible reasons:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3275

Comment: What SQL are you trying to use?

Comment: @Meakins - mysql flavor. @pekka: I've edited my original question.

Comment: This is possible as of version 8.0.19; `INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6) AS alias` ([link to manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`INSERT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) doesn't allow for aliases. Why would you need one in an INSERT statement anyways? You can only `INSERT` into one table at a time.

Comment: +1: Only reason I can see the need for an alias is if in a correlated subquery...

Comment: I was asking if it makes sense because, I do understand that I do not know all the mysql possibilities on queries, so, and since I learned that it's a good pratice to use alias in order to better understand what are we using... I thought that this would be pertinent. Still, the answer part: "The Insert syntax doesn't allow for aliases" was all that I needed to know for now. ;) For reasons, or probably reasons, see my question edition earlier today. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Convenience, flexibility and consistency in syntax.

Comment: If you have inherited a database that uses a reserved word as a column name

Comment: Then wrap the column name in backticks. ``

Comment: It is now possible to alias as of version 8.0.19; `INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6) AS alias` ([link to manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))

Answer (score 22):

Alas, it's not possible as can be seen by the [INSERT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html).  Note how it just says `[INTO] tbl_name` with no mention of `[AS] alias`, whereas the [Update syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), which does allow aliases, says "table_reference" and [further documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) states this can expand to *table_factor* which includes `tbl_name [AS] alias`.

It's unfortunate because having the ability to use table aliases on INSERTs would be very useful for [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statements.  Especially when performing checks on the columns like in this example:

```
insert into very_long_table_name_that_can_be_modified_one_day_or_during_testing (
    mykey, 
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    <column99>
)
select
    mykey, 
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    <column99>
from subquery
on duplicate key update 
    column1 = ifnull(values(column1), very_long_table_name_that_can_be_modified_one_day_or_during_testing.column1), 
    column2 = ifnull(values(column2), very_long_table_name_that_can_be_modified_one_day_or_during_testing.column2), 
    column3 = ifnull(values(column3), very_long_table_name_that_can_be_modified_one_day_or_during_testing.column3), 
    <column99>;
```

If the table name changes, one has to modify lots of lines of code compared to just having an alias at the beginning which is used in the query.

Comment: This should rather be a comment. But upvoted anyways, as it's very important

Comment: I have same issue how can one handle this ? my column name is amigous.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386803/mysql-insert-from-select-with-conditional-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: It is now possible to alias as of version 8.0.19; `INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6) AS alias` ([link to manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))